# Azure synapse spark pool creating delta table at Azure storage account

Tags: azure-synapse

Are there any example on the web to create a delta table using SQL API
to create a delta table at Synapse spark pool

Create table default.testing (col1 ...) using delta location 'abfss:....'

I see authentication error during the creation .

My Question is

1. When using SQL API , to create delta table , what credential is actually using?
2. Can use linked service to create the delta table ?
3. How can permanently mount a storage account container?

Comment: Could you please share the error message which you are experiencing?

Comment: it's confidential . ... but it says something like authentication error. is it possible to show some steps on how to do that? remarks: synapse is create in managed virtual network